# convert json string into POJO containing @key

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I have a json string as shown below.

```
{
    "input_index": 0,
    "candidate_index": 0,
    "delivery_line_1": "5461 S Red Cliff Dr",
    "last_line": "Salt Lake City UT 84123-5955",
    "delivery_point_barcode": "841235955990"
}
```

I want to convert into POJO of class as shown below.

```
public class Candidate {

    @Key("input_index")
    private int inputIndex;

    @Key("candidate_index")
    private int candidateIndex;

    @Key("addressee")
    private String addressee;

    @Key("delivery_line_1")
    private String deliveryLine1;

    @Key("delivery_line_2")
    private String deliveryLine2;

    @Key("last_line")
    private String lastLine;

    @Key("delivery_point_barcode")
    private String deliveryPointBarcode;
}
```

I am trying to convert json to pojo using jackson as shown below.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Candidate candidate = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,Candidate.class);
```

When I run the code I am getting all null values in pojo because jackson is looking for attribute name in the json string instead of name given in @key. How do tell Jackson to map values based on @Key?

I used @JsonProperty before and had no issue converting into pojo. The Candidate class is provided by third party and they are using @key(com.google.api.client.util.Key) annotation for attributes. So, I can't change the class.

Comment: Note that in Jackson you could just use `PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`.

Comment: Thanks for your help chrylis. I got only few values using this PropertyNamingStrategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this maven dep :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

And convert like this :

```
Candidate candidate = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance().fromString(output,Candidate.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ebrahim. Actually I have a list of Candidates. I am doing

             List<Candidate> candidates = Arrays.asList(new JacksonFactory().fromString(jsonInString, Candidate[].class));

 and I am getting error. Do you know how to convert list of objects using JacksonFactory?

Comment: List<Candidate> in place of Candidate[].class?

Can you please give entire statement?

Comment: @choom `ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance().fromString(output,ArrayList<Candidate>.class);`

Comment: Getting compilation errors.

List cannot be resolved to a variable.
Candidate cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @choom I update my comment. It should be `ArrayList`

Comment: @choom It should work. Are you sure import `java.util.ArrayList`? And what is the complete error?

Comment: Yes I imported. This error is for new ArrayList<Candidate>.class - 

ArrayList cannot be resolved to a variable.
Candidate cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @choom Ah my bad. Use this : `ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance().fromString(output,new ArrayList<Candidate>().getClass());`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ebrahim. Yes, I am getting all the values. But, I am getting com.google.api.client.util.ArrayMap. How do I convert 'com.google.api.client.util.ArrayMap' to List<Candidate>?

Comment: @choom You're welcome. `new ArrayList<Candidate>(arrayMap.values());`

Comment: Sorry, I am getting list of arraymaps. How do I convert list of arraymaps to list of Candidate?

Comment: `ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance().fromString(output, new ArrayList<Candidate>().getClass());`

`Candidate candidate = candidates.get(0);`
<br/>

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.api.client.util.ArrayMap cannot be cast to com.smartystreets.api.us_street.Candidate

Comment: @choom It seems jackson doesn't care about `ArrayList<Candidate>`. So do another approach please. Make a class and wrap list of candidates there. I mean create a class with one property named `List<Candidate> candidates;` and parse the json as this new class

Comment: I don't think I that works. The json string has list of strings. It contains square brackets [ ] and class with list expects { [ ] }

Comment: @choom Yes it needs to add `{`, `}` to the json string you get. But I wondered why `fromString` method does not return the correct class

Comment: @choom Try this please. `List<Candidate> listCandidates; JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance().createJsonParser(output).parseArray(listCandidates, Candidate.class);`

Comment: You rock! works perfect! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not able to change the class , you can use GSON as well to convert it back to Candidate class. I am suggesting this *only*  because you cannot change the annotation in the POJO class that you have.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String jsonInString = "{\"input_index\": 0,\"candidate_index\": 0,\"delivery_line_1\": \"5461 S Red Cliff Dr\",\"last_line\": \"Salt Lake City UT 84123-5955\",\"delivery_point_barcode\": \"841235955990\"}";

    Candidate candidate = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Candidate.class);

    System.out.println(candidate);
```

Although this is no replacement for the JACKSON Annotation and object mapper you have , using GSON you are covered pretty much in this case on the Source POJO provided

edit *you can also use JacksonFactory as below*

```
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

    Candidate candidate2 = new JacksonFactory().fromString(jsonInString, Candidate.class);

    System.out.println(candidate2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ramachandran. Actually I have a list of Candidates. I am doing

List<Candidate> candidates = Arrays.asList(new JacksonFactory().fromString(jsonInString, Candidate[].class));

 and I am getting error. Do you know how to convert list of objects using JacksonFactory?